# Many of the tools are missing

Tags: android-studio

When I'm designing Android app using Android studio I can not see most of the tools in palette like analog,digital clocks,date picker and time picker. Etc..  how do I get them.

Answer (score 0):

these are the codes for date and time picker dialogs 
       DatePickerDialog  StartTime = new DatePickerDialog(this, new    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,   int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                 newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                activitydate.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
              }

```
      }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),    newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

 btn_checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
 StartTime .show():

 });
```